# How do I change a box that has text in so it only has colour in?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, text

I am currently making a connect four game, I have been advised to use some existing code that I have previously used on a noughts and crosses game.

The problem I have is trying to change the noughts and crosses into colours. The code I currently have is ( http://pastebin.com/AkCBLnmt ). I am wanting to change x to green and o to red.

I have tried the following but it didn't work:

```
$(this).colour("Red");

$(this).colour("Green");
```

Could someone please advise me how to change the text ( x & o) to colours red and green.

Thanks

Comment: $(this).css("color","Red");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the background color

```
$(this).css('background-color', 'red');
```

If you want to change the text color

```
$(this).css('color', 'red');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 $(this).css({'color','red'});
```

Remember, that code (generally) prefers Americanised spelling.

If this doesn't work for you, could you post the accompanying HTML?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to change color of text:

```
$(this).css("color","red");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery.css() to change your style as follows:

```
$(this).css({'color':'red'});
$(this).css({'color':'green'});
```

For more style U want to change,U can use

```
$(this).css({'color':'red','display':'block','margin':'10px'});...
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$('.colours').each(function(){
 if($(this).text() == 'x') {
  $(this).css('color','green');
 }else{
  $(this).css('color','red');
 }
});
```